# How to show html page using link tag

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am able to load my web page using the iFrame in my application. But iFrame is taking more time to load the html. Want to use the link tag to load that html. But don't know how to use that as the iFrame

```
<iframe src="http://www.test.com"></iframe>

<link rel="import" href="https://www.test.com/" target="_parent">
```

In above examples, iFrame is loading page fine, but I am not seeing the html page with the link

Comment: `link rel="import"` is [not supported in any browser except Chrome and Opera](http://caniuse.com/#feat=imports), by the way.

Comment: By removing that 'rel' also it is not working. I am not able to display the html

Comment: ... right, because that's not what the `link` tag does. All a `link` tag does is establish a relationship between the current page and the URL. Only certain [values for `rel` are supported and do things](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types) (e.g., `"stylesheet"`). There's a potential value of [`"prerender"`](http://www.w3.org/TR/resource-hints/#h-prerender) that could do something like what you're asking for, but it's [not supported in all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=link-rel-prerender). It still would not render the HTML; just make it faster to navigate to.